# JavaScript Code Architecture - Use Constructor Functions Or Not

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

Please help me decide whether I should use a function's prototype object and the "new" keyword or completely stay away from constructor functions.

**Situation:**

Function called `widget()` that will be called 10-15 times to initialize each widget on the page. `widget()` contains quite a few internal methods.

Each time `widget()` is called, the function needs to return an object that acts as an API to operate on the widget.

**Question**

1)  Do I put all the internal methods inside `Widget()` under its prototype property? It does not make sense but the main reason for this is to not re-instantiate the internal functions every time `widget()` is called.

But if I do put the internal functions in prototype, each instantiated `w` object (`w = new Widget();`) has access to internal private methods.

2)  If I stay away from constructor functions and `new` keyword and structure my code as down below, how do I fix the performance concern of the internal functions getting re-instantiated every time `widget()` is called.

```
function widget()
{
   var returnObj = {};

   /* Add internal functions but this will be re-instantiated every time */

   return returnObj;

}
```

Comment: 15 objects is not likely to cause a problem. I, however,  prefer to leave methods on the prototype

Comment: Why are worrying about encapsulation? This is javascript, not .NET or Java.

Comment: @CesarCanassa encapsulation can just be an organizational tool. Someone looking at the code can easily tell that the encapsulated things are only used by the things around them. Of course, it's not really an issue if you're using multiple source files and glueing them together somehow, you can just minify everything and wrap it in an IIFE.

Comment: @GGG If organization is the only concern this can be achieved by adding a comment telling that the method is private or using Python underscore notation.

Comment: @CesarCanassa I don't think it's the only concern, encapsulation has practical advantages as well. Suppose you have different programmers making different widgets, each widget in its own file, and all of the files are run through Closure Compiler or similar. You'd probably want to make sure that no widget is accidentally interfering with another... you'd want encapsulation. You could handle it at build time, and let each file represent a separate scope, or you could design things so that the process of defining a widget naturally involves encapsulation, e.g. using a callback function.

Comment: Also, even if organization were the only concern, I think there's more to it than just documenting things. I think organization is more about where things are in proximity to one another. Good organization means I can find what I'm looking for without having to read every comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bit of a tradeoff here.  As you seem to already understand, methods you put on the `.prototype` are publicly available, but that is the most efficient places to put methods as they are automatically added to all new copies of that object in a very efficient manner.  When using `.prototype` for methods, there is only one copy of your methods and a reference to that single copy is automatically added to all new instantiations of that object.

But, javascript doesn't have private methods built-in and the only work-around for that involves not using the `.prototype` for them or for any methods that need to call the private methods.

This [article by Doug Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) is a pretty good description of how you can create privacy for either data or methods in any object.

In either case, I don't see any reason to avoid using the `new` keyword to create new objects.  You can make either `.prototype` or private methods work with `new`.

But, if you want to achieve truly private methods, then you can't use `.prototype` for either the private methods or any methods that need to access them so you have to decide which is more important to you.  There is no single correct answer because your need for privacy is situation-specific.

In my coding, I generally don't enforce privacy and I do use `.prototype` and `new`.  I designate "non-public" methods on the prototype by starting their name with an underscore.  This is a notational convention, not an access enforcement scheme.

In answer to your second question about avoiding the `new` operator and reinstantiating methods, I'd just ask why you're doing this?  What are you gaining?  I'm not aware of any downsides to using `new`.  As best I understand your decision about whether to use `.prototype` vs. manually create/assign methods in your constructor should be about the need for private methods.

FYI, 15 objects is hardly going to create a significant difference in performance either way here.  I would evaluate your need for true privacy and make your decision based on that.  If you HAVE to enforce privacy, then go with the Crockford method for implementing private methods.  If you don't HAVE to have true privacy, then use `.prototype`.  I don't see a reason here to avoid using `new` in either case.

Comment: Thanks for your very insightful answer. To answer your question with regards to dismissing "new" keyword, my understanding was that the biggest benefit of the "new" keyword was to transfer the constructor's prototype objects to each variable that calls the function with "new". If I do decide to not use prototype, I figured why even bother with "new" and call widget() without it. Not using "new" seems more native JS.

Comment: Using `new` is perfectly `native` JS.  I find the use of `new` more semantically descriptive in my code.  It's more obvious to a reader of the code that a new object of a particular type is being created.  When you don't use the `new`, the reader has to know what your function returns in order to know what that line of code does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a metaconstructor* pattern to get around this.

```
function defineCtor(metaCtor) {

  var proto = new metaCtor();

  var ctor = proto.hasOwnProperty('constructor') ? 
             proto.constructor : new Function();

  return (ctor.prototype = proto).constructor = ctor;

}
```

Now you have a function that constructs constructors (or more accurately constructs prototypes and returns constructors).

```
var Widget = defineCtor(function() {

  function doInternalStuff() {

    // ...cant see me

  }

  // this function ends up on the prototype

  this.getFoo = function() { return doInternalStuff(); };

});

// ...

var myWidget = new Widget();
```

---

**Explanation**

`defineCtor` takes a single anonymous function as a property. It invokes the function with `new`, creating an object. It assigns the object as the prototype property of a new constructor function (either an empty function, or the generated prototype object's own `constructor` property), and returns that function.

This provides a closure for your internal functions, addressing your question 1, and sets up the constructor/prototype pair for you, addressing question 2.

---

**Comparison**

Compare the `defineCtor` technique to the following two examples.

This example uses the prototype, and has problem 1: the internal stuff is not encapsulated.

```
function Widget(options) {
  this.options = options;
}

Widget.prototype = {

  getFoo: function() {
    return doInternalStuff();
  }

};

// How to encapsulate this?
function doInternalStuff() { /* ... */ }
```

This example sets up everything in a constructor, and has problem 2: each time it constructs an object, it instantiates new function objects for each property.

```
function Widget(options) {

  this.options = options;

  function doInternalStuff() { /* ... */ }

  this.getFoo = function() {
    return doInternalStuff();
  };

}
```

This example uses the technique described above to provide encapsulation while still leveraging the prototype:

```
var Widget = defineCtor(function() { 
  //                    ^
  // This function runs once, constructing the prototype.

  // In here, `this` refers to the prototype.

  // The real constructor.
  this.constructor = function(options) {

    // In function properties, `this` is an object instance 
    // with the outer `this` in its prototype chain.

    this.options = options;

  };  

  function doInternalStuff() { /* ... */ }

  this.getFoo = function() { return doInternalStuff(); };

});

// ...

var myWidget = new Widget();
```

---

This approach has a few benefits, some more immediately obvious than others.

- It provides encapsulation. You could do this by wrapping the first "comparison" example in an immediately invoked function, but this approach may be cleaner and more easily "enforced" in a team setting.
- It's extensible. You can give your "metaconstructor" functions their own prototypes, with function properties like "extends", "mixin", etc. Then, inside the body of `metaCtor`, you can write things like `this.extends(BaseWidget)`. The `defineCtor` API never needs to change for any of this to happen.
- It "tricks" Google Closure Compiler, Eclipse, jsdoc, etc. into thinking you are defining the actual constructor function rather than a "meta function."  This can be useful in certain situations (the code is "self-documented" in a way these tools understand).

<sup>* As far as I know, the word "metaconstructor" is completely made up.</sup>

Comment: I seem to be pretty confused by what defineCtor is trying to accomplish. Please elaborate or point to some resource that discusses this metacontstructor pattern. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user715489 I made some edits, let me know if that clears things up at all. I haven't seen this technique discussed much, I'm not sure what the proper name for it is, or if there is one. I just call it "metaconstructor" because it sounds cool.